# How fix sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fecthall'?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to get datas from cursor, but I get `sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fecthall`. I did searches but I didn't find solutions.
Also, does my definition good ?

```py
def config(ID_):
    root = Toplevel()
    connexion = sqlite3.connect('Base_SAV.db')
    curseur = connexion.cursor()
    curseur.execute("SELECT Nom FROM Client WHERE ID = (?)", (ID_,))
    Nom = curseur.fecthall())
    Label(root, text = Nom).pack()
    curseur.close()
```

Comment: it has to be `fetchall` , not `fecthall` - small typo with `c` and `t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo,

**Change:**

`fecthall` to `fetchall`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
curseur.fecthall())
```

to

```
curseur.fetchall()
```

Comment: there is also typo with `c` and `t` - you could add this.